# At one point of time, only one section would be opened

Tags: ios, uitableview

when i click first section getting follwing error:

```
Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.2/UITableView.m:1076
2014-02-26 14:12:38.935 ExpandableTableCells[1865:a0b]

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 8 from section 0 which only contains 1 rows before the update'
```

give me solution...
thanks...
code:

```
#pragma mark - Expanding

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canCollapseSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  if (section>=0) return YES;

   return NO;
  //return YES;
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"------->%d",section);

    if (section==0)
    {
        if ([expandedSections containsIndex:section])
               {
                   // return 5; // return rows when expanded
                   NSLog(@"%d",[self.alpha count]);
               return [self.alpha count];
                }
        return 1;
    }
    if (section==1) {
        if ([expandedSections containsIndex:section])
        {
            // return 5; // return rows when expanded
             NSLog(@"vvv%d",[self.numbers count]);
            return [self.numbers count];

        }
        return 1;
    }
    if (section==2)
    {
        if ([expandedSections containsIndex:section])
        {
            // return 5; // return rows when expanded
             NSLog(@"%d",[self.colors count]);
            return [self.colors count];

        }
        return 1;
    }

    return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    if (indexPath.section==0) {
               if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:indexPath.section])
        {
            if (!indexPath.row)
            {
                // first row
                cell.textLabel.text = @"Alaphabet"; // only top row showing

                if ([expandedSections containsIndex:indexPath.section])
                {
                    cell.accessoryView = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeUp];
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.accessoryView = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeDown];

                }
            }
            else
            {
                // all other rows
                cell.textLabel.text = [self.alpha objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                cell.accessoryView = nil;
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;



            }
        }

    }
    if (indexPath.section==1) {

        if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:indexPath.section])
        {
            if (!indexPath.row)
            {
                // first row
                cell.textLabel.text = @"numbers"; // only top row showing

                if ([expandedSections containsIndex:indexPath.section])
                {
                    cell.accessoryView = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeUp];
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.accessoryView = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeDown];

                }
            }
            else
            {
                // all other rows
                cell.textLabel.text = [self.numbers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                cell.accessoryView = nil;
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            }
        }

    }
    if (indexPath.section==2) {
                if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:indexPath.section])
        {
            if (!indexPath.row)
            {
                // first row
                cell.textLabel.text = @"colors"; // only top row showing

                if ([expandedSections containsIndex:indexPath.section])
                {
                    cell.accessoryView = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeUp];
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.accessoryView = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeDown];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // all other rows
                cell.textLabel.text = [self.colors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                cell.accessoryView = nil;
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

            }
        }

    }


    return cell;
}
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:indexPath.section])
    {
        if (!indexPath.row)
        {
            [self.tableView beginUpdates];
            // only first row toggles exapand/collapse
            [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

            NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
            NSLog(@"section------%d",section);
            BOOL currentlyExpanded = [expandedSections containsIndex:section];
            NSLog(@"current expand------%d",currentlyExpanded);

            NSInteger rows;

            NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [NSMutableArray array];

            if (currentlyExpanded)
            {
                rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
                [expandedSections removeIndex:section];
            }
            else
            {
                [expandedSections addIndex:section];
                rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
                NSLog(@"rows------%d",rows);
            }

            for (int i=1; i<rows; i++)
            {
                NSIndexPath *tmpIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:section];
                [tmpArray addObject:tmpIndexPath];
                NSLog(@"temp array----->%@",tmpArray);
            }

            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            if (currentlyExpanded)
            {
                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

                cell.accessoryView = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeDown];

            }
            else
            {
                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
                NSLog(@"open index------%d",openSectionIndex);

                if (openSectionIndex != -1)
                {
                   [tmpArray removeAllObjects];
                    rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:openSectionIndex];

                   [expandedSections removeIndex:openSectionIndex];
                    for (int i=1; i<rows; i++)
                    {
                        NSIndexPath *tmpIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i
                                                                       inSection:openSectionIndex];
                        [tmpArray addObject:tmpIndexPath];
                    }

                    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray
                                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

                }
               openSectionIndex=section;

                    cell.accessoryView =  [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeUp];


            }
            [self.tableView endUpdates];

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is my array need load in sections:self.alpha=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G",@"H" nil];
    self.numbers=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
    self.colors=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"yellow",@"blue",@"green",@"red",@"pink",@"orange", nil];

Comment: yes...i need to load letters in section1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
    int selectedIndex;
    UITableView *menuTableView;
    NSMutableArray *colorsArray, *numberArray, *alphaArray ;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
selectedIndex=50;
colorsArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"red",@"yellow",@"pink",@"none", nil];
numberArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6", nil];
alphaArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e", nil];

menuTableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 404) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
menuTableView.delegate=self;
menuTableView.dataSource=self;
menuTableView.separatorColor=[UIColor grayColor];
[self.view addSubview:menuTableView];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 3;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   int  count=0;
   if (section ==selectedIndex) {
        switch (section) {
            case 0:
                count=  colorsArray.count;
                break;
            case 1:
                count=  numberArray.count;
                break;
            case 2:
                count=  alphaArray.count;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        count=  1;
    }
    return count;

}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        return 60;
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text =colorsArray[indexPath.row];
        break;
        case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text =numberArray[indexPath.row];
        break;
        case 2:
            cell.textLabel.text =alphaArray[indexPath.row];
        break;

        default:
        break;
    }

           return cell;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 60;
}
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
UIButton *titleButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
titleButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30);
[titleButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[titleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
titleButton.tag = section;
NSString *sectionName;
switch (section)
{
    case 0: sectionName = NSLocalizedString(@"Colors", @"Colors");
        break;
    case 1: sectionName = NSLocalizedString(@"Numbers", @"Numbers");
        break;
    case 2: sectionName = NSLocalizedString(@"Alabaphet", @"Alabaphet");
        break;
    default: sectionName = @"";
        break;
}
[titleButton setTitle:sectionName forState:UIControlStateNormal];
return titleButton;
}
-(void)handleTouchUpInside:(UIButton *)sender
{

if(selectedIndex== sender.tag)
{
  selectedIndex=50;
}
else
{
  selectedIndex= sender.tag;
}

[menuTableView reloadData];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// secondviewcontroller *sec =[[secondviewcontroller alloc]init];
switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
      NSLog(@"%@",colorsArray[indexPath.row]);
        //sec.arrayobjectInsecondClass =colorsArray[indexPath.row];
        break;
    case 1:
        NSLog(@"%@",numberArray[indexPath.row]);
        //sec.arrayobjectInsecondClass =numberArray[indexPath.row];
        break;
    case 2:
        NSLog(@"%@",alphaArray[indexPath.row]);
        //sec.arrayobjectInsecondClass =alphaArray[indexPath.row];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
//    [self.navigationController pushViewController:sec animated:NO];

}
```

Comment: @user3331527 if it help you please mark question as solved if you got issue with the code let me know

Comment: thanks @Charan Giri.my code is tableview contain three section at the same time one section should be open others are closed...sections are alphabets,numbers,colors...i need to add different rows based on array   size for each sections

Comment: .its work fine....thanks.but i need to load above mentiond array for colors..thanks i will try it..

Comment: Hi answer is edited according to your requirement please take a look at it

Comment: thank you very much...according to your code the section started with what the array contains...it wolud be better for putting heading for each section...i tried following code...

Comment: - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *sectionName;
    switch (section)
    {
        case 0:
            sectionName = NSLocalizedString(@"Colors", @"Colors");
            break;
        case 1:
            sectionName = NSLocalizedString(@"Numbers", @"Numbers");
            break;
            // ...
        case 2:
            sectionName = NSLocalizedString(@"Alabaphet", @"Alabaphet");
            break;
        default:
            sectionName = @"";
            break;
    }
    return sectionName;
}

Comment: check answer it was updated

Comment: how do you get indexpath.section in handleTouchUpInside method...i getting error...

Comment: sorry replace indexPath.section with sender.tag  answer updated

Comment: thanks but its not showing colors section

Comment: do u mean it is not expanding...if so on button click, check the count or print array and section no,

Comment: sorry i did mistake..now its working thanks...then can i have uisearchbar and search according section opened..

Comment: need to pass array value one view to another view Ex:if i click red in  color section it should display in next view control..